# How long does it take for a Sim to die from hunger?

Tags: the-sims-2

How long does it take for a Sim to die from hunger? In particular, I mean on The Sims 2 (TS2) for consoles. Does it differ from controllable Sim to visiting NPC?

I want to kill visitors, but they don't seem to die from food poisoning, so I turn to starvation, by trapping them in sleep in a bed by blocking the exits. They can't die in their sleep; I must let them escape the bed to die from starvation, but if I release them too early, they will simply leave. If they return, they won't be starving anymore. I can't see a visitor's Motives like I can with my controllable Sims who live on the lot, so I know the safe amount of time to keep them trapped until I know that they are guaranteed to die from starvation when they awake.

Comment: "I want to kill visitors" - Man, I know the feeling.

Comment: If you just want to kill them and don't care about the method then I'd suggest you just build a small room around them with no openings or doors.

Comment: @MorbidEntree I think visitors use a portable hole exit after a while if you just trap them.

Comment: @NiteCyper No, I've done it a few times myself on the PlayStation 2 version of this game.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really sure on this but I know that more activity reduces their stat bars quicker. [Here is](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20111119114425AA6Wdcf) a duplicate question on yahoo answers but I don't think it's exactly what you are as it cheats to make them a household member.

Must you starve them? I always found the best way was to make a swimming pool and remove the ladder or else place fireworks spuriously around your house(once you don't mind it burning down that is)!

Comment: (1) Pools can be expensive, and I think that I tried this unsuccessfully. (2) Fireworks require the workbench skill item, which is also expensive. I think there's other inconveniences to fireworks as well. Most importantly, the fire spawned by setting one off indoors is not guaranteed to spawn under they who set it off, thus impractical.

Comment: All you need is a pool size of two blocks, one for ladder and another so they can move away while you delete the ladder, but if it doesn't work on guests then there's no point. But the fireworks is an easy enough solution, make a small separate room, when they enter delete the door!

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no way to see their traits to see if they are actually hungry. I'd leave em in that bed for as long as possible (weeks in game even) just to be sure.

something I always did was bring them to a secluded "shed" with a firework in the center and rugs all around.